# BinaryFileResponse : The content cannot be set on a BinaryFileResponse instance

Tags: symfony

I try to download a file (Attachment here) from a Controller

Here is my code :

```
/**
 * @param Request    $request
 * @param Attachment $attachment
 *
 * @Route("/message/{thread_id}/download/{attachment_id}", name="faq_download_attachment")
 * @ParamConverter("attachment", options={"id" = "attachment_id"})
 *
 * @return BinaryFileResponse
 *
 * @throws \Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\FileNotFoundException
 */

public function downloadFiletAction(Request $request, Attachment $attachment)
{
    $mountManager = $this->get('oneup_flysystem.mount_manager');
    $fileSystem = $mountManager->getFilesystem('faq');
    return new BinaryFileResponse($fileSystem->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix() . $attachment->getFilename());
}
```

This code :

```
$fileSystem->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix() . $attachment->getFilename()
```

return an absolute path (Which is correct)

[image]
Finally, I get this error =>
**The content cannot be set on a BinaryFileResponse instance.**

It seems that when I instanciate a BinaryFileResponse, symfony puts it’s content to NULL (that what I want)  but when I put the return statement. my content is replaced by a void string which is a bad thing because the following function of BinaryFileResponse is throwing an exception.

```
public function setContent($content)
{
    if (null !== $content) {
        throw new \LogicException('The content cannot be set on a BinaryFileResponse instance.');
    }
}
```

Moreover, if I delete the if statement in the setContent Method Everything works like a charm. (but this is not the best thing to do)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

I've tested your code and it worked for me. Try replacing the return statement by this:

```
return BinaryFileResponse::create($fileSystem->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix() . $attachment->getFilename());
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, This is not working for me, I use Symfony 2.4 maybe the error comes from here ?

Comment: I'm using 2.6 and trying both  `return BinaryFileResponse::create(__FILE__);` or `return new BinaryFileResponse(__FILE__);`, successfully triggers the download of the controller file itself. Try that, just in case is something wrong with he path of the file. Other than that, I would advice upgrading symfony to see if that solves the problem, because the code looks fine.

Comment: Sorry, I'am late, __FILE__ give me the same error. I'am gonna try with the latest symfony version, thank you again for your help

Comment: Hi, I've solved my problem, there was a listener which modify my Response. (the error was hidden in the stack trace)

Comment: I knew the code you showed was correct! Glad you solved the issue eventually :)